# Apparent inconsistency using std::floor

Tags: c++, std, floor

I have noticed something very odd when using std::floor.  I'm am compiling C++ on ubuntu.  I'm trying to floor a double to the nearest hundredth and I'm checking the cases where the input value is already rounded to the nearest hundredth and I'm getting inconsistent results.

My code:

```
double hundredthFloor(double value){
  double hundredth = 0.01;
  return hundredth * std::floor( value / hundredth);
}
```

In most cases it works,

```
value = 99.87 gives output 99.87

value = 99.879 gives output 99.87

value = 0.39 gives output 0.39
```

However:

```
value = 0.29 gives value 0.28

value = 0.47 gives value 0.46
```

I've tried many input values and so far only 0.29 and 0.47 seem to output a value one decimal below what I'd expected.

Has anyone seen anything similar?

Comment: Do you know about float representation ? You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: There's not enough information here.  How can 99.87/0.01 give output 99.87?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for what you see is that some of the values in your example, such as `0.01` and `0.29`, cannot be represented exactly using `float` or `double`.

You can get a better view of what is going on if you print the result with many significant digits:

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(15) << (value / hundredth) << endl;
```

When `value` is `0.29`, this [prints](http://ideone.com/20SJKJ)

```
28.999999999999996
```

This number is very close to 29, but `floor` truncates it to 28 anyway.

One way to address this is to add [epsilon](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon) to the result of division:

```
return hundredth * std::floor( value / hundredth + numeric_limits<double>::epsilon());
```

Comment: Thought I'd add: the program can probably be made to work more reliably by e.g. Adding 0.5 to the quotient before taking the floor.

Answer (score 0):

What's your EPS value? I always use the EPS values
to check first if my calculation is wrong or if it is the lack of precision of the computer:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
cout.precision(17);
cout << fixed << 0.29 << endl;
cout << hundredthFloor(0.29) << endl;
```

You will get something like:

```
0.28999999999999998
0.28000000000000003
```

This is because a `double` can't always represent a decimal number exactly, [see this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). This means that sometimes a number will be a little more or less than you expect; floor will not take this into consideration, and thus `0.29` will internally be represented as `0.28999999...` and rounded down to `0.28`.

A simple solution is to add a very small number, such as [`numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon), before calling `std::floor`:

```
double hundredthFloor(double value){
  double hundredth = 0.01;
  return hundredth * std::floor( value / hundredth + std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() );
}
```